# Why the configuration setting 'cfg_file_path' is returning FALSE value with function ini_get() and returning proper value with function get_cfg_var()?

Tags: php, function, configuration, directive, built-in

I'm using **PHP 7.3.5** on my laptop that runs on **Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit operating system**.

I've installed the latest version of **XAMPP** installer on my laptop which has installed the **Apache/2.4.39 (Win64)** and **PHP 7.3.5**

I executed below code and see the output in my web browser :

```
<?php 
    echo 'Value using get_cfg_var() : '.get_cfg_var ('cfg_file_path');
    echo '<br>'; 
    echo 'Value using ini_get() : '.ini_get('cfg_file_path');

    echo '<br>';

    echo 'Value using get_cfg_var() : '.get_cfg_var ('display_errors');
    echo '<br>'; 
    echo 'Value using ini_get() : '.ini_get('display_errors');

    echo '<br>';

    echo 'Value using get_cfg_var() : '.get_cfg_var ('post_max_size');
    echo '<br>'; 
    echo 'Value using ini_get() : '.ini_get('post_max_size');
?>
```

The output of above code is as below :

```
Value using get_cfg_var() : C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Value using ini_get() :
Value using get_cfg_var() : 1
Value using ini_get() : 1
Value using get_cfg_var() : 8M
Value using ini_get() : 8M
```

My question is why I'm getting `FALSE` value when I use the configuration setting `cfg_file_path` with the built-in function `ini_get()`?

As per my knowledge both of the built-in functions `ini_get()` and `get_cfg_var()` are used to get the value of a configuration option/configuration setting. Actually, this is working fine when I tried other configuration settings(viz. `display_errors` and `post_max_size`) with both these functions.

Then why it's not working with `ini_get()` and work properly with `get_cfg_var()` for configuration option `cfg_file_path`?

I also noticed that, from the output of `phpinfo()` that I got into my browser I could see the settings `display_errors` and `post_max_size` but not the setting `cfg_file_path`. Why so?

Why the setting `cfg_file_path` is not getting displayed in the output of `phpinfo()`? Where does it exist?

Someone please clear all of my above doubts.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

[get_cfg_var](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-cfg-var.php) returns the value from `php.ini` directly, while the [ini_get](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get) returns the runtime config value.